How to align objects using only guide lines in office suite
In google slide and ms power point (actually almost in every application where you can move objects on a canvas) helplines can be used as alignment mechanism. For example I can simply move object to the center of the screen or another bigger object and expect two magical helplines to appear out of nowhere aligning original object.
Helplines are present in Libre Impress as well, though I can't use them to align or center objects for some reason. Here is some solution I have tried, but they didn't work:

Aligning objects using position and size menu: tooo slow and uncomfortable.

Manually placing one horizontal and one vertical snap line in the centre of the screen: it worked, but I still can't place object in the exact center of bigger object.

Enabling helplines: I did it from the begging


I also considered switching to Only Office but notice that helplines are limited there as well. Are there way to enable this feature?
